# Google Maps CustomMarker OverlayView click event on mobile not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlay-view

I've created a CustomMarkar using google.maps.OverlayView.

I've added DomListener to it in the draw function:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function (event) {
    alert("div");
    google.maps.event.trigger(self, "click");
});
```

I've added it to floatPane

```
var panes = this.getPanes();
panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
```

When I create a new CustomMarker I add a DomListener to it:

```
let overlay = new CustomMarker(
    myLatlng,
    this.map,
    options
);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(overlay, 'click', function (event) {
    alert("overlay");
});
```

And finally ther is a listener on the map:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', function (event) {
    alert("map");
});
```

Everything works fine on PC browser:
First fires the alert(map), after it alert(div) and finally alert(overlay).

But on mobile devices only the alert(map) fires....

What is the solution to make this work on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

> use 'touchend' event

In your code just add touch start event listener too

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(overlay, 'touchend', function (event) {
    alert("overlay");
});
```

This worked for me.